# Is it possible to write a VLC plugin in Python?

Tags: python, vlc

Is it possible to write a VLC plugin in Python? If so how do you go about this?

I've seen the [vlc.py](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings#Download) file, all I can tell is you can write an application with functionality of VLC, but can you actually write something that you can open up in VLC that adds additional functionality, without going into the C code and recompiling everything?

Answer (score 5):

According to the VLC plug-in (or modules as they are called in VLC) [writer's guide](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aHacker%27s_Guide/Module_Writers_Guide):

> Different programming languages can be used at least in theory. (The main VLC code base only uses C, C++ and Lua, and on MacOS Objective C.)

So, it looks totally possible. Now, according to the [same resource](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aHacker%27s_Guide/Module_Writers_Guide) you can also create "out-of-tree" modules, which means that to add them to to VLC's functionality you *don't* have to recompile VLC.

If you want more information, or a walk-through on how to make these modules I would highly suggest checking out that link.

You mentioned the [VLC.py](http://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings) file. If you're going to use those Python binding, check out these [examples](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=tree;f=examples;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Can you tell me how to make a plugin for VLC using C++?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965454/how-to-write-vlc-plugin-that-can-interact-with-the-operating-system